# Getting list items closer together in CSS

Tags: html, css

I've got an unordered list with a few list items. I'm trying to decrease the spacing between the list items, but they won't get any closer than they already are. Anyone have any suggestions?

Here is the relevant code:

```css
ul.mainNav {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 185px;
}

li.mainNavItem {
  color: blueviolet;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 130px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mainNav">
  <li class="mainNavItem">hi</li>
  <li class="mainNavItem">hello</li>
  <li class="mainNavItem">welcome</li>
  <li class="mainNavItem">hallo</li>
</ul>
```

I've tried playing with the margins, but even at .01px, the list items wouldn't get closer together. I do want some space between them, albeit very little, so creating a bar wouldn't solve my problem either.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: First of: stop using `float` unless you really know what you're doing. Explore the magic of CSS **Flex**. Also, why don't you provide an image of the desired (or explain better) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` here

**1)** If you gonna add `display: flex;` on `ul`, then there won't be any space between its children.
**2)** You can add `gap` on the `ul` for space between 2 `li`.

```
gap: 1px;            // space between two li
```

```css
ul.mainNav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 1px;
}

li.mainNavItem {
  color: blueviolet;
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #000000;
  width: 130px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mainNav">
  <li class="mainNavItem">hi</li>
  <li class="mainNavItem">hello</li>
  <li class="mainNavItem">welcome</li>
  <li class="mainNavItem">hallo</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `li + li {margin-left: 1px; }` can you explain why the last li should have a 1px left margin and the first one not as well a 1px right margin? `gap: 1px;` is a far better solution.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan `li + li` is not the right tool here. Thanks

Answer (score -3):

One option might be to use negative margin? It seems to work with your example.

```css
margin-left: -10px;
```

```css
 ul.mainNav{
    float: right;
    padding-right: 185px;
}

li.mainNavItem{
    color: blueviolet;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: 130px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mainNav">
    <li class="mainNavItem">hi</li>
    <li class="mainNavItem">hello</li>
    <li class="mainNavItem">welcome</li>
    <li class="mainNavItem">hallo</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is `-10px;` a magic number you subjectively decided it fits best? What if the background color is say `rgba(0,0,0,0.2)` ?